# How to get the preview images (css sprites) for the loaded video?

Tags: youtube-api

I can't find in the [Youtube Player API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) the method(s) to receive the preview images for the loaded video. 
I'm not talking about thumbnail, but the preview that image appears when the viewer hovers the progress bar on the player.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain these are called storyboard on YT and are served as a giant image that gets sliced client-side. I don't think there is a legal, official API for this.